# How to forward meeting invitations

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, windows-10-calendar-app

I am using Outlook 2016 and I'm trying to forward meeting invitation to a group of people...When I click on Use form, there are no forms listed and the rule wont let me go past that point.

How do I create a form?

Comment: Hi, can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I may not quite understand your question. Which form do you mean?

Normally, you can click Forward under Meeting tab:
[image]

If you want to create forms for meetings. I think you can check this TechNet thread: [Create Form to pass information](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e7eb006d-166b-43c5-857e-511d04b41469/create-form-to-pass-information?forum=outlook)

Open a meeting and then choose Developer > Design this form.